# Contents of text file magically deletes self, using shell to save file

Tags: shell, io, text-files

### What I'm doing

My code basically pulls the resolution of my screen and saves it to a text file.
I can look at the content with cat or just open it in a text editor.

### Problem

However after a few seconds (even if I never open the file), the contents of the text vanish and the 9 bite file becomes a 1 bite file and completely empty.

I'm at a loss, any info?

---

My code:

```
savedir=/Users/myname/Documents/Geeklets/Displays_temp.txt
rezold=$(</Users/myname/Documents/Geeklets/Displays_temp.txt) 
echo "$rezold"
rez=$(xdpyinfo | grep dimensions | awk '{print $2}' | awk -Fx '{print $1, $2}')
echo "$rez" > "$savedir"

if [ "$rezold" != "$rez" ]; then
    if [ "$rez" == "1280 777" ]; then
        osascript /Users/myname/Documents/Geeklets/smallscreen.scpt 
    else
        osascript $HOME/Scripts/Geeklets/largescreen.scpt
    fi  
fi
```

Comment: The `$(< ...)` syntax looks fishy. I would have used `$(cat ...)` instead.

Comment: @JesperE: what's fishy about it?  It's a Bash extension, and acts like `cat` but without invoking a separate process.

Comment: Does the script run multiple times? Because if it is not, something else is touching your file. Also: You never check if the `xdpyinfo` call succeeds or the parsing actually works. If one of the above fails, you get an empty file with a single newline (because `$rez` is empty).

Comment: Note that `savedir` is a misnomer (it is more like `savefile`). The second line should be `rezold=$(<$savedir)` rather than writing out the entire file name again. You've not shown us the output you get. You should really echo `$rez` after you set it so you can see what is in it. You should do `cat "$savedir"` after echoing to it so you know what's in it (and show us so we know too). Note that the shell command `[` does not necessarily recognize `==` as a command; it is a Bash extension (the equality operator is `=` instead).  What do the two `.scpt` scripts do?  Could they modify the file?

Comment: Also note that a 1 byte file is not completely empty; it contains 1 byte of data and an empty file contains 0 bytes of data.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ok, then I blame it on me not being aware of all bash extensions. :)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  I have done the echo $rez and i get "1280 777".  It saves the value to the file and then I'm having trouble figuring out how the file end up with only 1 byte in it when it started with 9.

I'm still new to bash scripting.  The two scripts have zero chance of modifying the text file.

Comment: I'm not sure what else to suggest. Add an `ls -l` command on the file before and after the big `if` block. Or change the location of the file for a while and see if the relocated file gets clobbered. If the file is OK when the script exits, then some other process (a `cron` job?) is doing the damage. If the relocated file is damaged too, you've got gremlins. Have you run the script with `bash -x`?

Comment: I'll poke around.  Eventually i'll find the problem and post it here =).  I 'm not familiar with bash -x.  But i'll give it a try!

Comment: Good suggestion about saving it to another location.  It's not clear to me why but for some reason this fixes the problem!  Thanks for all the feed back everyone gave me!